# Constraint after SQL modify

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have two tables:

1. TableA
2. TableB

I have a constraint and relation between my tables.

I modify something on my TableA or TableB (for example: change datatype, or add a new column). Should I drop and create the constraint again?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: standard version of mssql

Comment: You may or may not, depends on what you're changing. SQL Server will tell you if your modification won't be allowed because the constraint depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you don't need to recreate a constraint for new columns.

For datatypes, it depends whether the alteration is on a contrainted column or not. If it is constrainted column, you first need to drop constraint then make alteration and create the constraint again.

Most RDBMS systems do not allow alteration of datatypes on constrainted columns.